# For complex queries which is better sql or mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, google-bigquery

I just want to know which one is better performance-wise for complex queries "SQL" or "MongoDB".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your queries are complex, SQL is the way to go. MongoDB is what's known as a NoSQL database. It is very fast, however it sacrifices robustness and has weak relational guarantees. Contrasting, SQL is resistant to outages and guarantees consistency between queries. Furthermore, NoSQL doesn't support unions, while SQL does, so for complex queries albeit slightly slower, SQL is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

I think. Your question is not really specific. But i think it depends on what you want to build. When you have table with too many relationships, it should be better to use relational database like PostgreSQL. Because PostgreSQL is three times faster than MongoDB for Joins and Aggregations. Otherwise go with MongoDb. Its also on the language you use in Bankend. MongoDB is a document-based database, who uses JSON-Object as document. For this reason, When you have Nodejs, deals very good with JSON-Objects, for your backend development is the perfect Match.